# GCC deadcode elimination

Tags: c, compilation, dead-code

Does GCC, or do compilers in general, remove variables which are operated on, yet do not at all affect the result of the code? For example, say main only contained

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     a += 10;
     b += 10;
}
printf("%d", a);
```

Is the variable b ever present in memory or even operated on after compilation? Would there by any assembly logic storing and handling b? Just not positive whether this is something that's counted under deadcode elimination. Thanks.

Comment: Every compiler can behave differently. And even the same compiler can behave differently with different options It's likely there is no "memory" involved at all in this simple piece of code. The values, if they exist, are likely to be loaded in registers only. To get a precise answer just compile the code yourself with the `gcc` version and flags you are interested in and have a look at the assembly output.

Comment: @kaylum right, should've been more precise with differentiating between memory and registers. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  This is a very common optimization.

The best way to answer such questions for yourself is to learn a little bit of assembly language and read [the code generated by the compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/Yar5Ej). In this case, you can see that not only does GCC optimize `b` entirely out of existence, but also `a`, and it compiles the whole function into just the equivalent of `printf("%d", 100);`.

Comment: I see. I was looking through some objdumps where it did not seem like this type of optimization was occurring, but see that one of the -O flags has to be set for gcc. Thanks for the response!